# How to create reg-expression to find url file extention is present?

Tags: java, regex

The following is a sample string I'm using:

> http://www.asfradio.com/device.asp?u=username&p=password&s=east

Current checks I use in my code:

```
if (data.endsWith(".asf") || (0 < data.indexOf(".asf")))
```

So in this case my check fails because yes there is a .asf string but it's followed by radio and that makes my logic bad since this link is not asf type...

What I want is a regular expression which returns true if ".asf" is found and the next character after "f" is not a letter.

Hopefully it make sence...

Comment: Have you looked at the Java regex documentation?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java's regex engine, you have the [word boundary anchor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) `\b`

Search for `\\.asf\\b`. In order to use that with String.matches(), you will have to wrap it with `.*`:

```
boolean found = inStr.matches(".*\\.asf\\b.*");
```

Better yet, store the compiled pattern in a constant:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\.asf\\b");
```

And use it like this:

```
boolean found = PATTERN.matcher(inStr).find(); // not .matches()
```

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm always glad when people remember to say thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to check for the file extension is to first get the path. Java's URL class is what you need to do this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://blah.com......");

if (url.getPath().endsWith(".asf") {

   // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use word boundary `\b` :

```
\.asf\b
```

May be you have to double escape in java.

Answer (score 0):

May be end of line

```
.*\.asf$
```

Not end of line

```
.*\.[^a-zA-Z].*
```

Answer (score 0):

The next best check would be to assume, that the sequence is either at the end of the string or somewhere in the middle and followed by a question mark:

```
if (data.endsWith(".asf") || data.contains(".asf?"))
```

Answer (score 0):

this only matches when .asf is at the end of the string or right before a `?`

```
Pattern.compile("\\.asf(\\?|$)")
```